# How to let a Windows Store App start another Windows Store App

Tags: windows, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have an Android App (let's call it StackApp) that has an overview of weblinks to the Google Play store. When a user clicks on one of these links StackApp will check if the selected link is from a installed App on the current device. If so, that App will start. If not, it opens the Google Play store page of that App.

I would like to be able to do the same with a Windows Store App. Is this possible?

URI Activation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452686.aspx) is not an option because not all Windows Store Apps have an URI scheme name. (or am I wrong?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't and you are not supposed to be able to do that. Apps can talk to each other indirectly via sharing or directly via URI mappings. For apps that don't support sharing nor have URI associations, launching them from your application is impossible.

You should use sharing for sharing content and app supported scheme for launching. What you want is a general purpose launch which isn't supported in neither Windows Phone nor Windows Store.